# Adding Emails tPHP code

Tags: php

I found this code on here earlier today and I tried modifying it but I get an error code when I try to add more emails to the code (it starts with 2) not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the example

This is my modified Code (tried adding a third email to the bottom and I'm getting a php error)

```
// Add the custom checkout field
add_filter( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'restaurant_location_checkout_field' );
function restaurant_location_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

    woocommerce_form_field( 'restaurant_location', array(
        'type'        => 'select',
        'class'       => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'       => __('Select Location', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'    => true,
        'options'     => array(
            ''   => __('Please select an option', 'woocommerce' ),
            '4289 boul St-Jean' => __('4289 boul St-Jean', 'woocommerce' ),
'3559 boul St-Charles' => __('3559 boul St-Charles', 'woocommerce' ),
            'Baton Rouge' => __('Baton Rouge', 'woocommerce' )
        )
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'restaurant_location' ));
}

// Process the checkout (checking)
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'restaurant_location_field_process');
function restaurant_location_field_process() {
    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if ( ! $_POST['restaurant_location'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please select a food option .' ), 'error' );
}

// Update the order meta with field value
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'restaurant_location_field_update_order_meta' );
function restaurant_location_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['restaurant_location'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_restaurant_location', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['restaurant_location'] ) );
    }
}

// Display field value on the order edit page
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('Food options', 'woocommerce').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_restaurant_location', true ) . '</p>';
}

// Conditional Email recipient filter based on restaurant location
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'conditional_email_recipient', 10, 2 );
function conditional_email_recipient( $recipient, $order ) {

    $location = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_restaurant_location', true );
    $recipient = $location == '4289 boul St-Jean' ? ',nicks@mtygroup.com' : ',nicsoti@yahoo.com' : ',nicks@mtygroup.com' ;
    return $recipient;
}
```

This is the original Code I found

```
// Add the custom checkout field
add_filter( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'restaurant_location_checkout_field' );
function restaurant_location_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

    woocommerce_form_field( 'restaurant_location', array(
        'type'        => 'select',
        'class'       => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'       => __('Food options', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'    => true,
        'options'     => array(
            ''   => __('Please select an option', 'woocommerce' ),
            'New Orleans' => __('New Orleans', 'woocommerce' ),
            'Baton Rouge' => __('Baton Rouge', 'woocommerce' )
        )
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'restaurant_location' ));
}

// Process the checkout (checking)
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'restaurant_location_field_process');
function restaurant_location_field_process() {
    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if ( ! $_POST['restaurant_location'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please select a food option .' ), 'error' );
}

// Update the order meta with field value
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'restaurant_location_field_update_order_meta' );
function restaurant_location_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['restaurant_location'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_restaurant_location', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['restaurant_location'] ) );
    }
}

// Display field value on the order edit page
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('Food options', 'woocommerce').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_restaurant_location', true ) . '</p>';
}

// Conditional Email recipient filter based on restaurant location
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'conditional_email_recipient', 10, 2 );
function conditional_email_recipient( $recipient, $order ) {

    $location = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_restaurant_location', true );
    $recipient = $location == 'New Orleans' ? ',test1@example.com' : ',test1@example.com';
    return $recipient;
}
```

Comment: Could you maybe provide the error you get? Or did I miss that part?

Comment: Sorry, I get a "x" hint and when I upload it it breaks page. Thanks a lot for the response. You guys are GREAT. Hope I learn enough to hep others someday. Merry X-Mas and Happy Holidays to you and yours

Answer (score 0):

Change this line :

```
$recipient = $location == '4289 boul St-Jean' ? ',nicks@mtygroup.com' : ',nicsoti@yahoo.com' : ',nicks@mtygroup.com' ;
```

to :

```
switch ($location) {
    case '4289 boul St-Jean':
        $recipient = ',nicks@mtygroup.com';
        break;

    case '3559 boul St-Charles':
        $recipient = ',nicsoti@yahoo.com';
        break;

    default:
        $recipient = ',nicks@mtygroup.com';
        break;
}
```

Or just modify it to suits your needs

Comment: Just 1 question do I leave 

   return $recipient;
}

as the end of the segment or do I just close it like you have?

Again, Thanks so much for the help. It's awesome of you guys. Merry CHristmas and Happy Holidyas to all of you.

Comment: It works with 4 emails so I think I'm good to go, Thanks a lot. You really hooked me up. Can Not thank you enough. Have a great holidays.

Comment: Leave th `return $recipient;` part at the end